# como cambiar el titulo del error 404 en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

hola a todos llevo días buscando como cambiar el titulo del error 404 de wordpress, actualmente me aparece " pagina no encontrada " y quiero cambiar ese titulo por otro, pero no he podido encontrar en que parte del script lo cambio, espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varias posibilidades

Si tu tema tiene una página llamada `404.php` ahí deberías cambiar el título.

Si no tienes esa página, puedes hacerlo con un filtro en tu página de `functions.php`. Solo agrega este fragmento

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'toledano_cambio_404', 10);
function toledano_cambio_404($title) {
  if (is_404()) {
    return 'No encontramos lo que buscabas';
  }
  return $title;
}
```

> #### Importante
>
> No indicas que versión usas, pero este ejemplo solo funciona con la versión de Wordpress **4.7.4 o superior**.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvió muchisimo